# Operador LIKE MYSQL en PDO

Tags: mysql, pdo

Podrían explicarme como funciona LIKE en PDO, le comparto mi listar_cliente.php, consulta a la tabla y lista en un DATATABLE funciona con sentencia sencilla pero no con LIKE, el error es de sintaxis al parecer debo hacer un poco más complejo, haciendo uso de bindParam y el metodo execute sin parametro, pero no entiendo como hacerlo ¿Alguien me puede explicar?

```
<?php
// Requires
require("../database/database.php");
$nombre_cliente = $_POST['nombre_cliente'];
if(!empty($nombre_cliente)){
    try{
        $conexionWorkspace = new conexionBDWorkspace();
        $sentencia = $conexionWorkspace -> conectarBD() -> prepare("SELECT * FROM subcreditos WHERE NOMBRE = :nombreCliente");
        $sentencia -> execute(['nombreCliente' => $nombre_cliente]);
        $registros_clientes["data"] = [];
        while($clientes = $sentencia -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)){
            $registros_clientes["data"][] = $clientes;
        }
        echo json_encode($registros_clientes);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Ocurrió un problema al consultar y listar los comentarios, error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Eh aquí la respuesta con uso de bindValue

```
<?php
// Requires
require("../database/database.php");
$nombre_cliente = $_POST['nombre_cliente'];
if(!empty($nombre_cliente)){
    try{
        $conexionWorkspace = new conexionBDWorkspace();
        $sentencia = $conexionWorkspace -> conectarBD() -> prepare("SELECT * FROM subcreditos WHERE NOMBRE LIKE ?");
        $sentencia -> bindValue(1, "%$nombre_cliente%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sentencia -> execute();
        $registros_clientes["data"] = [];
        while($clientes = $sentencia -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)){
            $registros_clientes["data"][] = $clientes;
        }
        echo json_encode($registros_clientes);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Ocurrió un problema al consultar y listar los comentarios, error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```